# Why Sequelize Raw Queries don't return records from MySQL when I search by date?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have a MySQL database and I try to search in a tale using `created_at` and `updated_at` fields which are `timestamp` fields using this query

```
SELECT
    user_types.id,
    user_types.name,
    user_types.parent_id,
    user_types.entity_id,
    user_types.deleted_at,
    user_types.created_at,
    user_types.updated_at
  FROM user_types
  WHERE user_types.entity_id='ea438831-74aa-4d1a-80e6-eb31df7e2777' AND user_types.deleted_at IS NULL
  AND (user_types.created_at >= '2022-01-16 22:22:53' OR user_types.updated_at >= '2022-01-16 22:22:53')
```

But I get 0 records though when I run the same query in phpmyadmin I get the record I'm looking for so why doesn't Sequelize search correctly by date?

connection:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
process.env.MYSQL_USER,
process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
{
  host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
  dialect: 'mysql',
  port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
  dialectOptions: {
    multipleStatements: true,
    dateStrings: true,
    typeCast(field, next) {
      if (field.type === 'DATETIME') {
        return field.string();
      }
      return next();
    },
  },
  timezone: '+00:00',
  logging: false,
  pool: {
   min: 1,
   max: 500,
   idle: 10000,
   acquire: 60000,
  },
 },
);
```

I tried `AND (DATE(user_types.created_at) >= '2022-01-17 22:6:5' OR DATE(user_types.updated_at) >= '2022-01-17 22:6:5')` but it didn't fetch the record I can fetch from phpmyadmin

[image]

Comment: Check what SQL query Sequelize generates and compare with the working one

Comment: I get this by logging the query I pass to Sequelize. How can I get the query generated by Sequelize itself?

Comment: By turning on logging in Sequelize instance options